# Why is my Revert File menu always disabled?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just switched from Sublime Text to Visual Studio Code. Just installed it, set up a new workspace (no Git setup yet). But no matter what I do with my files in editor, **File -> Revert File** menu is always disabled.

Does it need another setup so the menu would activate itself everytime my files get dirty?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me when I first open VS Code and the 'Explorer' panel is NOT open. As soon as I open the 'Explorer' panel, the 'Revert File' option becomes enabled.

I think it's a bug because there's no logical reason that I can think of for this behaviour.